# Custom push transition isn't working whereas the same custom present transition is

Tags: ios, swift, custom-transition

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions) and watched [the WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/) on this subject but I couldn't find my answer.

I have almost the same transition in my code. It is working pretty well when I am doing it as a presented view, but not as a pushed view.

It is supposed to animate a snapshot of the pushed view from a CGRect to the full screen and vice versa when popped.

Here is the code of my `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` class:

```
class ZoomingTransitionController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    let originFrame: CGRect
    let isDismissing: Bool

    init(originFrame: CGRect, isDismissing: Bool) {
        self.originFrame = originFrame
        self.isDismissing = isDismissing
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return Constant.Animation.VeryShort
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
            let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) else {
                return
        }

        let finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVC)

        toVC.view.frame = finalFrame

        let snapshot = self.isDismissing ? fromVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) : toVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
        snapshot?.frame = self.isDismissing ? finalFrame : self.originFrame
        snapshot?.layer.cornerRadius = Constant.FakeButton.CornerRadius
        snapshot?.layer.masksToBounds = true

        containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
        containerView.addSubview(snapshot!)

        if self.isDismissing {
            fromVC.view.isHidden = true
        } else {
            toVC.view.isHidden = true
        }

        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       animations: {
            snapshot?.frame = self.isDismissing ? self.originFrame : finalFrame
            },
                       completion: { _ in
                        if self.isDismissing {
                            fromVC.view.isHidden = false
                        } else {
                            toVC.view.isHidden = false
                        }

                        snapshot?.removeFromSuperview()
                        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to show a new View Controller using 2 ways: by **presenting** it and by **pushing** it.

My `FromViewController` is subclassing both `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`.

`FromViewController` class **presenting** the `ToViewController` (which works fine):

```
func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tappedButtonFrame = sender.frame

    let toVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToViewController")
    toVC.transitioningDelegate = self

    self.present(toVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let transitionController = ZoomingTransitionController(originFrame: self.tappedButtonFrame, isDismissing: false)

    return transitionController
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let transitionController = ZoomingTransitionController(originFrame: self.tappedButtonFrame, isDismissing: true)

    return transitionController
}
```

`FromViewController` class **pushing** the `ToViewController` (which doesn't work):

```
func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tappedButtonFrame = sender.frame

    let toVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToViewController")

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(toVC, animated: true)
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    switch operation {
    case .push:
        return ZoomingTransitionController(originFrame: self.tappedButtonFrame, isDismissing: false)

    case .pop:
        return ZoomingTransitionController(originFrame: self.tappedButtonFrame, isDismissing: true)

    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

When **pushing**, the delegate method is called and the ZoomingTransitionController performs its code fine (going in `animateTransition` until the end without notable issue). But on the screen, the snapshot view isn't display at any moment. The ToVC appears after the transition duration, but without anything else meanwhile.

I am running out of idea on how to debug this... Do you have any idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried to push it with help of dispatchAsync and main queue?

Comment: I did, not helping. I think the problem came from the snapshot I create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer by replacing the snapshot element (which was causing the problem) by a `CGAffineTransform` of the `toVC`.

Code is almost the same than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936555/navigation-bar-gets-adjusted-after-calling-completetransition-in-custom-transit).